# Display the profile information of a logged in user in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to create a profile view for the user that is currently logged in. I created a session_data array for when you log in that only contains their username. How would I retrieve the other values from the row depending on who is logged in? Do I have to add all that information to the session_data array?

I have the values ***first_name***, ***last_name***, & ***date_joined*** that I want to display alongside ***username***.

**Login Controller:**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('login');
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

function login_validation()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
  if($this->form_validation->run())
  {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    if ($this->login_model->can_login($username, $password))
    {
      $session_data = array(
        'username' => $username
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
      redirect('home');
    }
    else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
      redirect('login');
    }
  }
  else {
    $this->index();
  }
}

function enter()
{
  if ($this->session->userdata('username') != '') {
    echo "Welcome " . $this->session->userdata('username');
    echo '<a href="/index.php/logout">Logout</a>';
  }
  else {
    redirect('login');
  }
}

function logout()
{
  $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
  redirect('login');
}
}
```

**User View:**

```
<h4><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h4>
```

Comment: You have username in session. you can pass it in select query to fetch information for that username

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a method in login_model that retrieves the username info based on the username you send to it.

Something like this:

```
function get_user($username)
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($this->db->affected_rows())
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

On the other hand, I recommend you to use an existing authentication library.
[Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) is pretty good.

Good luck!